# Object argument to mock EXPECT_CALL

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I have a simple mock class:

```
class MockCanInterface : public lib::CanInterface {
 public:
  MockCanInterface() : CanInterface({"mock"}) {}

  MOCK_METHOD1(Write, bool(const lib::CanFrame& frame));
  MOCK_METHOD1(Read, bool(lib::CanFrame* frame));
};
```

In the test code I want to pass an object to the `Write` method. Is there a way to do this with `.With` clause? It works with passing argument directly, but now with `.With`. The code compiles, but fails during execution - the size of the object is correct, but the data isn't.

This works:

```
EXPECT_CALL(can_, Write(expected_command_))
        .WillOnce(Return(true));
```

This doesn't:

```
EXPECT_CALL(can_, Write(_))
        .With(Args<0>(expected_command_))
        .WillOnce(Return(true));
```

I admit that there may be something missing in the way the code sets the expected object.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is: The method Write() required a CanFrame argument passed by reference.

I suggest to use the **Actions** provided by GMock:
`SetArgReferee` - reference or value
`SetArgPointee` - pointer

You can find examples and much more [here](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md)

However this solution works for me, I hope for you too ;)

```
EXPECT_CALL(can_, Write(_))
        .WillOnce(SetArgReferee<0>(expected_command_));
```

or with the return value:

```
EXPECT_CALL(can_, Write(_))
        .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(expected_command_), Return(true)));
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Have you tried the code with mock `Write` taking `const lib::CanFrame&`?  I keep getting this error `error: passing 'const lib::CanFrame' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers`

Comment: you are right. It only works with a non-const reference. I can't find a solution to a const reference argument. However I leave my answer here, maybe it help someone to find the correct answer.